# Usage of anonymous functions in arrayfun with GPU acceleration (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, cuda, gpu, anonymous-function

I am new to the Parallel toolbox from Matlab R2012b and was wondering what the best way is to overcome the following problem.

I am analyzing the neighbourhood of every pixel in an image. Which is extremely good case for parallelization. However, I can't seem to get it working.

The main catch in the problem is that some "constant" arguments should be passed to the function. So the function should be called for every pixel, however, it also needs to access the surrounding pixels. (Preferable by passing the image as some sort of constant parameter and the coordinates of the pixel to be analyzed).

The output is one value per pixel.

At the moment I have this:

```
z2 = arrayfun(@(x) analyze(x, image, const1, ...), gpuArray(1:m*n));
```

Where x is the dummy-var, image a 2D matrix containing the luminance values of the image, const1 (and others) are function-constants (e.g. size of the analyze window). m and n are the size of the dimensions of the image.

However, I get this error

> Error using gpuArray/arrayfun
>   Use of functional workspace is not supported.

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Ruben

Comment: Can you post the code for `analyze`?

Comment: The message "Use of functional workspace is not supported" leads me to suspect that you can't create `workspace` variables from within a call to `arrayfun`.  I tried test this locally but alas my video card is too old and isn't supported.

Comment: @slayton Thx for your effort! I'm not at home atm, the analyze function is an example as the real code is very complex (although it exists solely out of arithmetics). However, a valid simplification would be "calculate the mean for every pixel and it's surrounding pixels. And I could figure out the rest. I will try to post some reference code asap.

Comment: @slayton different approaches (e.g. not using anon function) are also very appreciated

Comment: actually I suspect that the anonymous function might be the culprit as its bringing with it a portion of your workspace.  I can't be certain though, as I can't execute any calls to `gpuArray` on my machine.

Comment: @slayton that's what I'm starting to think as well. I tried other approaches as well. (E.g. using gpuArray as the datastructure for my algorithm, but it actually slowed the execution time by a factor of 3). Rewriting as Cuda C and linking it could work, but it will be a big investment of time without certainty. I'm thinking in the direction of global GPU variables or something, but this doesn't feel like the right thing to do. All suggestions are hugely appreciated!

Comment: are you using functional operators like plus(A,B) in your analyze function?

Comment: @RobertCrovella The functions that are used are exp(), mod(), ceil(), .* and inv() and standard aithmetics. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not supported by Parallel Computing Toolbox in R2012b. The gpuArray version of arrayfun currently does not support binding in the constant data to an anonymous function handle. Arrayfun arguments must be passed directly, and must all either be scalar or the same size.

If you could bind in the constant arguments, you would next discover that you cannot currently index into them (or perform any non-scalar operations on them).

Perhaps you might be able to build up your algorithm using supported routines such as CONV2 or FILTER2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you are probably right. However, I will not select this as the right answer yet, in the hope that somebody could provide me a workaround or something.

Comment: I'm afraid the best you can currently hope for is probably to use MATLAB's CUDAKernel functionality (unless you can pass in all the data you need as scalars).

Answer (score 0):

this is a very old post, but since I was struggeling with a similar issue, I wanted to share what I found out about this:

If you put your call of `arrayfun` within a function, you might be able to implement the `analyze` function as a nested function that has access to your constant arrays. However, this might require quite some effort in rewriting your code, because within the nested `analyze` function you cannot pass any full array to any other function, which means you have to rewrite everything in a way that you use only single indexed array entries of your constant arrays, e.g. in a for loop over the array. Accordingly all calls of functions like `size` etc. will not work and should be moved outside of `analyze` (at least this is the case for Matlab2015b, which I am using).
Here is an example of how it can be done (not mine):

https://devblogs.nvidia.com/high-performance-matlab-gpu-acceleration/

Best,

Hans-Martin